# Azure Table Storage REST API MERGE method in Angular 12

Tags: angular, azure, http, storage, rest

I want to use Merge operation in Azure Table Storage with REST API approach in Angular,

According to the [doc from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-or-merge-entity) , I need to send MERGE request to make it works.

| Method | Request URI |
| --- | --- |
| MERGE | https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/mytable(PartitionKey='myPartitionKey', RowKey='myRowKey') |

but seems that Angular not support MERGE method by default, it only support Get, Post, Put, Delete, Options, Head, Patch [by default](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#methods).

Can anyone teach me how to extend or customize HTTP method in Angular ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem after some studying.

Just use `request` method in `httpClient`

```js
  let options: { body: any, headers: HttpHeaders } =
    {
        headers: this.generateDefaultHeader(operator),
        body: payload
    };
    options.headers = options.headers.set('If-Match', '*');

    return this.http.request(
        'MERGE',
        `${this.entitiesEndpoint}${operator}`,
        options
    );
```